# Let's not make this complicated

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I'm something you like to share
>   with someone for whom you care.
>   Sometimes spicy, sometimes sweet,
>   Sometimes sweeps you off your feet.
>   Find me on the FM dial,
>   Coast to coast across the miles.
>   You've seen me in my make up
>   And you can make up with me.
>   I'm the X's to your O's.
>   Tell me then - who can I be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're a

> Kiss

I'm something you like to share
with someone for whom you care.

> Family/lovers share kisses

Sometimes spicy, sometimes sweet,

> An alternate definiton of kiss is "a small cake or cookie, typically a meringue." So a spicy/sweet meringue.

Sometimes sweeps you off your feet.

> A kiss can sweep you off your feet

Find me on the FM dial,
Coast to coast across the miles.

> Kiis FM "Coast to coast"

You've seen me in my make up
And you can make up with me.

> "Kiss and make up" (thanks Conman)

I'm the X's to your O's.

> XO is hugs and kisses where X's are the kiss

Comment: I would guess that the phrase "Kiss and make up" is part of it :)

Comment: Note that there's a clue in the title too.

Comment: Indeed. Title and line 7 are clues you are still missing.   Almost there!

Comment: I suspect the clue about finding me on the FM dial refers not to a station, but to the band, which also ties in to the clue about seeing me in my make up.

Comment: Why must it be one or the other?  ;-)

Comment: As all the hints have been solved now, though spread between comments and @shree.pat18's answer, I'm accepting this answer.

Answer (score 5):

To add on to @econoMichael's answer:

The title refers to:

> Keep It Simple Stupid - a design principle used in software development, among other areas